Razor Page with Multiple forms -After first form post , second form post or handler doesn't get hit say 400 error (this page isn't working)
I am facing one issue with Razor page that is having two forms on a one razor page.
First form having simple two text boxes and one submit button which is calling HanlderA to save data.
Second form with one text box and one submit button to get data created by 1st form on same page and submit button calling handlerB on server side .
Problem like after first form post call (after handler execution) , if trying to Submit (onPost) of second form ,it (browser) says that "This page isn't working " with HTTP 400 Error.
If I am using [ignoreantiforgerytoken] attribute at class level then all form post call work as expected with out above issues .
Note : I noticed in network call (F12)that in 1st form post _RequestverificationToken was there ... while in second form submit _RequestverificationToken was going blank and causing 400 bad request.
please suggest if any other or right solution  ?
tried by using @Html.Antiforgerytoken() inside second form but not worked .
then used [ignoreAntiforgerytoken] attribute to fix it temporary but looking for right fix ?

How are you submitting the form? AJAX? https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/336/ajax-posts-in-razor-pages-and-http-400-errors

since the anti-forgery value is tied to the form, if you open a form, open a new tab, open same form, the current anti-forgery value is set for the new tab.  (new tab submit will work, old tab submit will not work)  That's by design.  Likewise if you use something like an iframe for 2nd form, or you use the same anti-forgery token for two forms on one page.  One anti-forgery token per form, and per request.

I am using two forms on one razor page only .first form with two text boxes and submit button calling HanlderA to save data  while second form with one text box and submit button to show that data in Grid   calling HanlderB.   if i use form at a time both form works but if post 1st form and submit 2nd form to see data 2nd post doesnt work as _RequestverificationToken  was going blank in second post ?

Hi @NishantTyagi,  it works fine in my side without any issue. could you pls share your frontend code? More code would be helpful to resolve the issue.

in general you'd redirect after posting a razor page form, so it's hard to say what the issue is here.  Obviously you're not redirecting after posting or you wouldn't have two forms on one page to begin with.  You should include your code so we can be more helpful here.  (hard to understand why there's two forms on one page without seeing your code)

Here is a working demo below:
Index.cshtml
@page
@model IndexModel
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="HandlerA">
    <input asp-for="IsChecked" />
    <input  asp-for="Dep" />
    <button type="submit">Submit Form 1</button>
</form>

<form method="post" asp-page-handler="HandlerB">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit Form 2</button>
</form>

Index.cshtml.cs
[BindProperties]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {

    }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Dep { get; set; }

    public void OnPostHandlerA()
    {
        
    } 
    public void OnPostHandlerB()
    {

    }
}

Note: Be sure you do not specific the action attribute in the form, otherwise you need manually add token input by using @Html.AntiForgeryToken().
<form method="post" action="/?handler=HandlerA">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input asp-for="IsChecked" />
    <input  asp-for="Dep" />
    <button type="submit">Submit Form 1</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="/?handler=HandlerB">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit Form 2</button>
</form>

If you're using JavaScript or AJAX to load or update parts of the page dynamically, ensure the anti-forgery tokens are also refreshed and updated accordingly. Tokens can become invalid if they are not updated when forms or parts of forms are loaded dynamically.
